# app crashes after becoming active, when calling [UIImageView setImage:]

Tags: iphone, multithreading, crash, background, audiounit

I have an app with callbacks for recording and playing audio. From the recording callback, I call a function to update the GUI:

```
[mainViewController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateGuiAfterOnset) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

It works ok, but after I send the app to background (using the device's `home` button) and open it up again, the app crashes after the 2nd call to `updateGuiAfterOnset`, and specifically, it crashes after calling to:

```
[myUIImageView setImage:myUIImage];
```

The only things I do in `applicationWillResignActive` and `applicationDidBecomeActive`, are stopping and starting the audioUnit:

```
AudioOutputUnitStop(audioUnit);
```

and

```
AudioOutputUnitStart(audioUnit);
```

My intuition is that some variable is messed up during the going-to-background/foreground process, but that's only a guess.

Any ideas? Are there any recommended thing I need to do when going to background in a multi-threaded app?

**EDIT** The app crashes also if the gui-updating-method is called from the main thread (by tapping a button).

The relevant part from the crash report:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000008
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000027d8 objc_msgSend + 16
1   UIKit                               0x00009738 -[UIImageView setImage:] + 140
2   TimeKeeper                          0x00002b7a -[MainViewController updateGuiAfterOnset] (MainViewController.m:89)
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0003e2e4 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] + 16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like myUIImage is not valid. Was it autoreleased or manually realeased by mistake.

Comment: Indeed, I was setting it using `[UIImage imageNamed:]` , but I did not retain it (it is hold inside a C-struct which of course cannot be retained - now I see it's a bad idea...). Was it autoreleased when the app went to background?

Answer (score 1):

It would suggest myUIImageView is not retained.